# value placeholder in Domain classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, property-placeholder

I have a maven project in Eclipse called TdkUtils, with this pom.xml: This is a utils project. So I want to create a jar, put it in the repository and use it in another projects.

I have this domain class:

```
@PropertySource("recommended-mobile.properties")
public class RemoteUnit implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private RemoteUnitType remoteUnitType;

    private long remoteUnitId;

    private String serialNumber;

    private String imei;

    private String softwareVersion;

    private String msisdn;

    @Value("${AX1}")
    private String firmwareAX1;

    @Value("${AX1Pro}")
    private String firmwareAX1Pro;

    @Value("${AX5}")
    private String firmwareAX5;

 ...
}
```

But it's not replacing the values at all. Maybe its only possible in the config files ?

I also tries to put the values in the file `application.properties` with the same result

I also have in the configuration file the path to the domain classes

```
@ComponentScan(value="com.tdk.domain")
```

Comment: The values that will go over the placeholders are defined where? In the pom.xml file ?

Comment: in a properties file named recommended-mobile.properties inside the resources folder

Comment: Try adding the classpath in the annotation parameter, similar to `@PropertySource("classpath:/recommended-mobile.properties")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the ComponentScan("package PathOfYourDomainClassGoesHere") annotation on your Configuration class

Answer (score 0):

@COnfiguration,@ComponentScan(basePackage={""}),@PropertySource("classpath:*.properties)

The above 3 annotations are necessary to use to obtain the required result.